# Suggestion: Make it so you can widen the #mainbar div with your mouse to make it easier to read answers that overflow over the page

Tags: feature-request

It would be a great feature to make it so you can slide the right edge of the `#mainbar` div to the right in the web browser so that you can more easily read code that overflows and goes to the next line. As an example, take a look at this answer and how things go off screen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61976367 - you have to scroll around left and right to see the full answer and it interrupts the flow of reading the code (aforementioned div outlined in the red dashed border):

[image: Answer on the main site with code blocks that have horizontal scroll, with a visual indicator to show the width of the #mainbar div container element]

These days, not everyone follows the 80 character code line rule with our much larger wide screen monitors.

Comment: Sure, we don't all follow the 80 column "rule", but, I would still consider the code formatting here the issue.

Comment: It might help to show, visually, what that div is.

Comment: Also as much as I'd like to see the interface make better use of space on wide screens, I'm pretty sure staff has declined similar requests in the past for technical reasons (e.g., requests to make the suggested edit review interface wide enough to be, uh, usable - I have a userscript that does that and it's a night-and-day difference to usability).

Comment: @RyanM Basically the div that is the whole width of the question and/or answer. Not sure it is the right div either since there is a lot of nesting but essentially let's make it so you can drag and make the question/answer section wider the way you might widen a window on your computer with the mouse.

Comment: Re *"with our much larger wide screen monitors"*: I thought there was a trend of giving that up in exchange for mobility (even using smartphones). Perhaps I am wrong?

Comment: very much wrong, yes